# Meaning of "representation to"

Tags: word-meaning

> It was by no means unusual for conquered regions of the Empire to be
> governed by direct representations to the emperor.
>
> A history of Finland by Henrik Meinander

I have two versions:

1. Conquered regions of the Empire were governed by personal delegates of the Emperor.
2. Conquered regions of the Empire were governed by making direct reports to the Emperor.

Which one of these is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure its the first one. If you used the second meaning, the sentence wouldn't make sense at all, as that's what empires in the past did! Usually in this case "direct representations to the emperor" should mean high representatives of the emperor.